# Get latest x number of entries from huge database table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I have a huge chat log table in an sqlite3 database and I want to retrieve the latest x numer of entries from it.

I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10;
```

but this takes 3 seconds to complete due to the size of the table. Is there a way to retrieve the latest 10 entries faster?

Comment: Do you use already an index ?

Comment: Do you have an index on the time column?

Comment: I haven't used indexes before. I'll look into it